# Efficiency of using external IP to reach LAN device

Tags: lan, dynamic-dns, wan, cctv

I have a CCTV DVR that I use with a phone app. My home router updates DYNDNS, so the phone app uses to ______@dyndns.org as the IP. Here's what I have always wondered:

If I use the phone app while at home (i.e., connected to my local area network), and it uses the external IP (via DYNDNS.org) to establish the connection, does the traffic go point-to-point once established (i.e., between my phone's internal IP address on the LAN and the DVR's), or does the traffic continue via the same route that was used to originally establish the connection?  In other words, should I have two entries in the camera phone app (one for when I'm at home, and another for when I'm outside of the house)?

I have tested both, over the years, and have never seen a difference in how long it takes to establish the connection, nor have I seen a difference in performance.

Comment: Given how fast connections are the difference are measured in 1/1000 second (milli-second) or less range, but the local route, when you are at home, is the faster route even if it is only by a tiny amount.

Comment: This goes back to your router or ISP, your DNS query is going to return the public IP so your app will attempt to access that. Your router may catch it and return at that point (unlikely) or your ISP catches it at the gateway and returns (more likely), or lastely it goes out into the cloud somewhere and returns (bad implementation, but possible). The best possible answer would be to have a custom DNS entry inside your LAN on a DNS server, where abc123.dyndns.org translates to your internal IP on the LAN, and uses public DNS to get the public IP elsewhere.